# Python is returning a letter from a word in a list, but not the word

Tags: python

I have a list that gets generated like so:

```
#demographic


def race_list():
    demographic = []

    Dwarf_race = Dwarf_box.get()
    Elf_race = Elf_box.get()
    Human_race = Human_box.get()

    if Dwarf_race == 1:
        demographic.append("Dwarf")
    else: 
        pass
    if Elf_race == 1: 
        demographic.append("Elf")
    else: 
        pass
    if Human_race == 1: 
        demographic.append("Human")
    else: 
        pass
    return demographic
```

I then have a function that will call this list, make a random selection from it, and then read a file. Like so:

```
# gen_NPC.py
def run(demographic): 
    print(demographic) 
    set_race = random.choice(demographic).strip()
    print(set_race)

    gender = ['male', 'female']
    sex = random.choice(gender)
    first = open(set_race + '_' + sex + '.txt')
    name1 = first.readlines()
    first = random.choice(name1).strip()

    last = open(set_race + '_surnames.txt')
    name2 = last.readlines()
    last = random.choice(name2).strip()

    npcname = NPC(first, last)
    propname = npcname.name

    return propname, sex, set_race
```

This function gets called several times (by other functions) throughout the course of the main script running which is determined form user inputs. It does work on occasion, however `set_race = random.choice(demographic).strip()` will sometimes return a letter from one of the words in the list meaning the files can't be opened and I get something like this.

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1486, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "dnd_test.py", line 99, in MakeSettlement
    gen_market.run(num_market, demographic)
  File "/Users/username/Desktop/DnD/dndapp/DND_Beta_2.0/gen_market.py", line 9, in run
    gen_NPC.run(set_race)
  File "/Users/username/Desktop/DnD/dndapp/DND_Beta_2.0/gen_NPC.py", line 20, in run
    first = open(set_race + '_' + sex + '.txt')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'l_male.txt'
```

I have run this with `print(demographic)` and `print(set_race)` to confirm this.

Any idea why the `random.choice()` would do this?

Comment: You never need to use `else: pass`. `else` is not a required block.

Comment: `gen_NPC.run(set_race)` – You’re already running the `run` method shown above with a `set_race` value which—I assume—is a string and not a list of strings like `demographic`.

Comment: Martijn, yep, that's true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `set_race` to be a single character, `demographic` *must* have been set to a single string and not a list. At that moment `random.choice()` picks a single random letter from that string:

```
set_race = random.choice(demographic).strip()
```

`demographic` is taken from the argument passed in when calling the `run()` function, so you need to look at the code *calling* that function. Your traceback shows you were. You passed in a string, and not a list on this line:

```
  File "/Users/username/Desktop/DnD/dndapp/DND_Beta_2.0/gen_market.py", line 9, in run
    gen_NPC.run(set_race)
```

The fact that that line passes in `set_race` seems to indicate that you picked your NPC race outside the function and tried to pass that in.

You didn't share that part of the code, so we can't tell you why `set_race` there is not a list but a string. You evidently did not use the list returned by `race_list()` there (that that function uses a local name `demographic` too is independent from the name in `run()`).

Comment: Derp, yep sorry I was passing through a string, not a list of strings.